Can I execute the Jenkins IT test case in cucumber , along with SONAR and Fortify Scan in parallel
Actually, I want to reduce the time of my Jenkins pipeline, so I want to execute some of the step in parallel, I am not sure if such thing exists or not also what could be the disadvantage of doing things in parallel on Jenkins server. I want to execute IT test written in cucumber, sonar, fortify scan in parallel after the build of tomee based microservice is completed.
Tech stack
Maven
Docker
Tomee

Yes you should be able to. Is there any blocker or problem you ran into when trying?
